# ionic - :CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

When I want to build an application on ionic (a blank, test project), the command "ionic cordova build android" returns this error:

---

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 13.795 secs

```
Error: /home/usuario/testeo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/usuario/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/aapt: /home/usuario/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/aapt: no se puede ejecutar el fichero binario
```

### FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task `':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.`

### com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

---

I tried to reinstall many times Android SDK. I also tried differents versions of Android tools/platforms (25, 28) but it did nothing.

I've been dealing with this issue for more than 2 days at work, so i would really aprecciate if someone could offer some help :) .

My info:

```
     IONIC --> 3.12.0
     Gradle --> 4.3.1
     JVM --> 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
     OS --> Linux 4.17.14-202.fc28.i686 i386 FEDORA
     ANGULAR --> 1.0.0
     NODE --> 7.8.0
     NPM --> 4.2.0
     CORDOVA --> 7.0.1 ANDROID --> 6.2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a permission inside this

```
/home/usuario/testeo/platforms/android/gradlew
```

chmod -R 777 ./ (if ubuntu)